# Using loop to create new variables

Tags: r, loops

My data frame is called **Subs**.

My variables are `REV_4`, `REV_5`, `REV_6` etc

I want to create new variables to calculate percentage change of revenue. 
Eg:  `d.rev.5 <-  Subs$REV_5/Subs/$REV_4 -1`

I would like to use a loop to create these new variables. I've tried this:

```
for(i in 5:10){
Subs$d.data.[i] <- Subs$REV_[i]/Subs$REV_[i-1] - 1 }
```

But it **doesn't work**. 
I suspect it's not recognizing the `i` as part of the variable name.

Is there any way to get around this?  Thank you so much.

Comment: why do you **want** to use a loop? `Subs$d.rev.5 <- Subs$REV_5 / (Subs$REV_4 - 1)` should do.

Comment: Oh I guess I didn't explain myself properly. I have about 40 different revenue variables, i.e. REV_4, REV_5.......REV_39, REV_40 etc. and I was hoping to find a faster way to create a new variable to calculate their percentage change.

Comment: You should update your question with the output of `dput(head(Subs))` so others can see the structure of the data you're working with, and can therefore give you a solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't reference columns like you're attempting (`Subs$REV_[i]`), you need to create a string to represent the column.

What I think you're trying to do is (in the absense of your data I've created my own)

```
set.seed(123)
Subs <- data.frame(rev_1 = rnorm(10, 0, 1),
                   rev_2 = rnorm(10, 0, 1),
                   rev_3 = rnorm(10, 0, 1),
                   rev_4 = rnorm(10, 0, 1))

for(i in 2:4){
  ## looping over columns 2-4
  col1 <- paste0("rev_", i)
  col2 <- paste0("rev_", i - 1)

  col_new <- paste0("d.rev.", i)

  Subs[, col_new] <- Subs[, col1] / Subs[, col2]

}
```

---

```
## A note on subsetting a data.frame
Subs$rev_1   ## works
i <- 1
Subs$rev_[i] ## doesn't work
Subs[, rev_[i]] ## doesn't work
Subs[, "rev_1"] ## works
Subs[, paste0("rev_", i)] ## works
## because
paste0("rev_", i)  ## creates the string:
[1] "rev_1"
```

Comment: why one should use Subs[, paste0("rev_", 2)] ? cannot you use Subs[, 2] or Subs[,i]

Comment: That was exactly what I needed. Thank you so much!

Comment: @Learner you're right, you can, I just **assumed** they wanted to reference the column by name